# JAXB - can class containment be flattened when marshalling to XML?

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb

Say, I have two classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
class A {
    @XmlElement
    String propertyOfA;
    @XmlElement
    B b;
}

class B {
    @XmlElement
    String propertyOfB;
}
```

JAXB returns an XML formatted in the according way:

```
<a>
  <propertyOfA>valueA</propertyOfA>
  <b>
    <propertyOfB>valueB</propertyOfB>
  </b>
</a>
```

My question is **how to flatten the hierarchy in the XML?** So that I have:

```
<a>
  <propertyOfA>valueA</propertyOfA>
  <propertyOfB>valueB</propertyOfB>
</a>
```

Can this be done with annotations?

At the moment I am thinking to create a kind of wrapper class for A, that would have fields built the way I want to see them in the XML. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension to map this use case:

```
import java.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
class A {
    @XmlElement
    String propertyOfA;

    @XmlPath(".")
    B b;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: I ended up using this one, it works. And I thought XmlPath would become handy.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while for me, but let me give it a crack:

```
@XmlRootElement
class A {
    @XmlElement
    String propertyOfA;
    @XmlElement(name="propertyOfB")
    B b;
}
@XmlType(name="")
class B {
    @XmlValue
    String propertyOfB;
}
```

Edit: disclaimer- I havn't compiled or tried this.  But I believe it's how you do it.

Comment: +1 - If `B` only has one property then this is the way to go.  For more information see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html.  If `B` has more than one property then you can try the approach given in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8361819/383861

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to that question and the solution proposed: [Spring RESTful client: root tag exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312573/spring-restful-client-root-tag-exception)

Very helpful to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (with standard JAXB) would be using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. This way you could adapt the object hierarchy with the drawback of having to write the code that translates the object hierarchy into the adapted new class.
In your example however it wouldn't work as you would have to adapt class A which is your root. If however the hierarchy was deeper and you needed to make the adaptation one level lower than the root, then there wouldn't be a problem. A suggestion that might be useful is to write the code in the adapted entity, making it like a delegate to the object hierarchy, rather than the adapter, which would then be very thin.