# XML map EmbeddedId attribute

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jaxb

Having this Person entity in Java:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private PersonIdentity persondentity;
  private String name;
  private Boolean active;
  private Boolean closed;
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
  @XmlAttribute(name = "DateBirth")
  private Date birth;

  @XmlAttribute(name = "PersonName")
  private String personaName; 
}
```

and PersonIdentity which acts like a composite key:

```
 @Data
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @Embeddable
 public class PersonIdentity implements Serializable {

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;

  @XmlAttribute(name = "PersonId")
  private String personId;
}
```

I'm trying to map a XML like this into Person class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person personId="2017PIOE-A132" PersonName="John" DateBirth="19Apr2018 18:53" />
```

In the begining, without the composite key (@EmbeddedId), I was able to map the object, now with the PersonIdentity acting as a Primary Key, I can map other properties but not this one, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does this question have to do with jpa or hibernate? If I understand correctly, you're essentially asking how to flatten the object structure when marshalling an object into XML, which is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361634/jaxb-can-class-containment-be-flattened-when-marshalling-to-xml)

Comment: I added these tags because I thought it was related, (I am very new in Java sorry). I saw this example but I think is not the same. I need to map personId and convert it into PersonIdentity type, I also tried with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter but it is still not working. Furthermore I am using Intellij, (I do not know if MOXy is compatible)