# Spring Rest Template and JSON data

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm calling a 3rd party restful webservice that returns a complex JSON object.  Is there a way for Spring or any open source tool to auto generate the client side code object.

In Soap, I'm use to doing wsdl2java in cxf but I don't know what the equivalent is in the restful space.

In the end I would like to use the rest template to make the following call:
restTemplate.getForObject("url", generateObject.class)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is yes as long as you have json schema for your input file. 
I dont remember at the moment how this framework is called but it is google product.

It auto generates Java class annotated with Json. It is really good. I will look for name.

Comment: I dont remember at the moment I have to check on other laptop. I will let you tomorrow morning if ok

Answer (score 1):

For the same thing I used a framework called XStream (http://x-stream.github.io/). It's pretty light and will definately help you :)

Comment: I agree, I did it parsing a XML response from REST call. Take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312573/spring-restful-client-root-tag-exception